# получение вектора объекта

Tags: unity3d, vector

Возможно, глупый вопрос, но ответа не нашёл. Как получить вектор объекта?

Comment: Есть вопросы глупые, а есть абсурдные и бессмысленные оксюмороны типа `сколько минут в сантиметре?` и твой вопрос относится не к глупым. Вектор это направление, куда направлен лежащий на полу кубик? на юг? на юпитер? чуть левее чем, на хер?

Comment: Напиши конкретную цель, которую хочешь достичь: Для чего тебе вектор? Где ты будешь его использовать? Вставь хотя бы пару строчек из кода, так легче анализировать информацию